# Trouble making gallery page into three rows of columns

Tags: css, flexbox

In regular html I would use three `<div class="dream">` for each row of images on the page, but I added php code, so the images aren't linked in the html code, but uploaded from a database. How do I keep this style of CSS, but just make them three rows?

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 20px 0 20px;
}

.container .heading{
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.container .heading h3{
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222;
}
.container .box{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .box .dream{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 32.5%;
}

.container .box .dream img{
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="products-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">     
<div class="dream">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <a href="<?=url('index.php?page=product&id=' . ($product['url_slug'] ? $product['url_slug']  : $product['id']))?>" class="product">
            <?php if (!empty($product['img']) && file_exists($product['img'])): ?>
            <img src="<?=base_url?><?=$product['img']?>"  
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?=currency_code?><?=number_format($product['price'],2)?>
                <?php if ($product['rrp'] > 0): ?>
                <span class="rrp"><?=currency_code?><?=number_format($product['rrp'],2)?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this an css issue? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just figured it out by changing the code to: .container .box .dream{
  display: row;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.container .box .dream img{
  width: 32.5%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

Comment: But there is still this problem where there is empty spacing between the images. Maybe I will post another question about this issue i've run across before too.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution as answer? 
Also mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need each of your items to have a flex-basis of one-third (33.33%) to result in three columns.

There are [good interactive examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out by changing the CSS code to:

```css
 .container .box .dream{
 display: row; 
 width: 100%;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }
 .container .box .dream img{
 width: 32.5%; padding-bottom: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px; }
```